# bm problem with newcommand

Tags: macros, bm

Καλημέρα!

If I use the package `bm`, I have problems with the `\newcommand{\hm}{\mathop{}\!\text{ημ} \mathop{}\!}`.

**N.B.:** I don't have problems with the `\mathop{}\!\text{ημ} \mathop{}\!`, but with the `\newcommand{\hm}{\mathop{}\!\text{ημ} \mathop{}\!}`

As I 'm saying, the strange is that the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$\mathop{}\!\text{ημ} \mathop{}\! x$

\end{document}
```

is OK, but this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, amsfonts}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\hm}{\mathop{}\!\text{ημ} \mathop{}\!}

\begin{document}

$\hm x$

\end{document}
```

get's me an error.

What is happening?

Ευχαριστώ εκ των προτέρων!!!

Comment: Please note that `\text` is _never_ a good choice for something like this. It typesets in italic if the surrounding context is italic (for example inside a theorem construction), that was probably not what was intended. Sadly many users misuse the `\text` command.

Comment: I have to use the greek characters "ημ" in math mode (ημΑ=sinA). So I must use `\text` command. Or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do

```
\renewcommand{\hm}{...}
```

but there's a glitch: when `\bm` does its work, it redefines `\hm`. So `\hm x` would produce the expected result, but `\bm{\hm x}` wouldn't and just render the “x”.

I suggest to use a different name, such as `\hmop`.

I also suggest a different way to define such operators:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathgreek}{LGR}{maksf}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathgreek}{bold}{LGR}{maksf}{bx}{n}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\DeclareGreekMathOperator}[2]{%
  \begingroup\let\IeC\translate@greek
  \protected@edef\@temp{#2}%
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \unexpanded{\DeclareMathOperator{#1}}%
    {\noexpand\mathgreek{\unexpanded\expandafter{\@temp}}}%
  }\x
}
\def\translate@greek#1{\csname LGR\string#1\endcsname}
\makeatother

\DeclareGreekMathOperator{\hmop}{ημ}

\begin{document}

$\mathop{}\!\text{ημ} \mathop{}\! x$

$\hmop x$

$\bm{\hmop x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Where's the advantage in such a complicated definition? Try your code in an italics context:

```
\textit{abc $\mathop{}\!\text{ημ} \mathop{}\! x$ def}
```

would print ημ in italics as well.

Answer (score 4):

The `\hm` macro is defined by package `bm`:

> If there is a 'heavy' math version defined (usually accessed by a
>   user-command `\heavymath`) then a similar command `\hm` is defined
>   which access these 'ultra bold' fonts.

If you don't need it then use `\renewcommand{\hm}{patati patata}`.

Comment: However, `\bm{\hm x}` will not work.

Comment: @egreg thanks (of course I  was not aware of `\bm` redefining `\hm`)